# C++ some questions on boost::unordered_map & boost::hash

Tags: c++, hash, unordered-map, boost-unordered

I've only recently started dwelling into boost and it's containers, and I read a few articles on the web and on stackoverflow that a boost::unordered_map is the fastest performing container for big collections.
So, I have this class State, which must be unique in the container (no duplicates) and there will be millions if not billions of states in the container.
Therefore I have been trying to optimize it for small size and as few computations as possible. I was using a boost::ptr_vector before, but as I read on stackoverflow a vector is only good as long as there are not that many objects in it.
In my case, the State descibes sensorimotor information from a robot, so there can be an enormous amount of states, and therefore fast lookup is of topemost priority.
Following the [boost documentation](http://www.systomath.com/include/Boost-1_36/doc/html/unordered.html) for unordered_map I realize that there are two things I could do to speed things up: use a hash_function, and use an equality operator to compare States based on their hash_function.
So, I implemented a private hash() function which takes in State information and using boost::hash_combine, creates an std::size_t hash value.
The operator== compares basically the state's hash values.
So:

- is std::size_t enough to cover billions of possible hash_function
  combinations ? In order to avoid duplicate states I intend to use
  their hash_values.
- When creating a state_map, should I use as key the State* or the hash
  value ? 
  i.e: `boost::unordered_map<State*,std::size_t> state_map;`
  Or
  `boost::unordered_map<std::size_t,State*> state_map;`
- Are the lookup times with a boost::unordered_map::iterator =
  state_map.find() faster than going through a boost::ptr_vector and
  comparing each iterator's key value ?
- Finally, any tips or tricks on how to optimize such an unordered map
  for speed and fast lookups would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I have seen quite a few answers, one being not to use boost but C++0X, another not to use an unordered_set, but to be honest, I still want to see how boost::unordered_set is used with a hash function.
I have followed boost's documentation and implemented, but I still cannot figure out how to use the hash function of boost with the ordered set.

Comment: can you comment a bit on how do you evaluate that two States are the same? when you create e new State, how do you know if an already existing one cannot do the job already?

Comment: I compare all it's member variables to see if they are the same, ie:
Compare all accelerator data, compare all gyroscope data, compare all gps data, compare all actuator positions.
Those values are rounded up in order to avoid mantissa errors.
If and only If all that data matches two states, are they identical.
I was hoping that by creating a unique hash at construction time for a state, and then comparing hash values, I could speed things up.

Comment: i've added an answer; i hope its clear why you should not use any sort of hashing function for testing equality like this, and use an `ordered_set` instead as a State* index only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit muddled.

- What you say are not "things that you can do to speed things up"; rather, they are mandatory requirements of your type to be eligible as the element type of an unordered map, and also for an unordered set (which you might rather want).
- You need to provide an equality operator that compares *objects*, not hash values. The whole point of the equality is to distinguish elements with the same hash.
- `size_t` is an unsigned integral type, 32 bits on x86 and 64 bits on x64. Since you want "billions of elements", which means many gigabytes of data, I assume you have a solid x64 machine anyway.
- What's crucial is that your hash function is *good*, i.e. has few collisions.
- You want a set, not a map. Put the objects directly in the set: `std::unordered_set<State>`. Use a map if you are mapping **to** something, i.e. states to something else. Oh, use C++0x, not boost, if you can.
- Using `hash_combine` is good.

---

Baby example:

```
struct State
{
  inline bool operator==(const State &) const;
  /* Stuff */
};

namespace std
{
  template <> struct hash<State>
  {
    inline std::size_t operator()(const State & s) const
    {
      /* your hash algorithm here */
    }
  };
}

std::size_t Foo(const State & s) { /* some code */ }

int main()
{
  std::unordered_set<State> states; // no extra data needed
  std::unordered_set<State, Foo> states; // another hash function
}
```

Comment: I have an operator which compares states, based on their attributes, in order to ensure uniqueness. I was under the impression that using a unique hash value, I could do the same thing but faster. Comparing states meant comparing 9 dimensional data (accelerometer, gyroscope, gps) plus actuator positions. My intention was to create a unique hash from all that data at Construction time, and compare that hash value instead.
my hash_function is an implementation of boost::hash_combine, is that good enough ?

Comment: The container will already do the comparing of hash values for you, so you don't think about that. All you need is a type that is equality-comparable and hashable.

Comment: `size_t` is not necessarily `unsigned int`; it's a type that's guaranteed to be large enough to hold the size of any object you could create. By the way, it's large enough for the hash function by definition, since it's used as an index in the hash table, which in turn is an object, thus its size can be contained in a `size_t`.

Comment: Ok, I have implemented that, but when it comes to the equality operator, wouldn't it be faster to use the State's hash value instead of comparing all the member data ?

Comment: @Alex: That'd be **useless**. The container already knows that two elements with different hashes are different. The only time you need the equality operator is when you have several elements with the **same** hash value.

Comment: PS: What do you mean "hashable" ?

Comment: @Alex: exactly what I wrote in my answer: You need to provide a hash function for your object. I specialized `std::hash` directly so you don't have to mention it explicitly in the parameter list of your `unordered_set`. But it's up to you to provide that function (but you said you already have one).

Comment: I'm still a bit puzzled. Should I provide a publich hash function for class State ? Seeing your example I see that your hashing takes place in operator(), is that what you mean by hashable ?

Comment: The hash function has to be a free function or function object. I added another example. "Hashable" means that you have some sort of hash function around.

Answer (score 2):

An unordered_map is a hashtable.  You don't store the hash; it is done internally as the storage and lookup method.

Given your requirements, an unordered_set might be more appropriate, since your object is the only item to store.

You are a little confused though -- the equality operator and hash function are not truly performance items, but required for nontrivial objects for the container to work correctly.  A good hash function will distribute your nodes evenly across the buckets, and the equality operator will be used to remove any ambiguity about matches based on the hash function.

std::size_t is fine for the hash function.  Remember that no hash is perfect; there will be collisions, and these collision items are stored in a linked list at that bucket position.

Thus, .find() will be O(1) in the optimal case and very close to O(1) in the average case (and O(N) in the worst case, but a decent hash function will avoid that.)

You don't mention your platform or architecture; at billions of entries you still might have to worry about out-of-memory situations depending on those and the size of your State object.

Comment: Platform/Arch is Linux amd64 with 6GB of Ram, and the simulation is done using webots. It is the controller I am worried about.
About hashing and collisions, would you recommend boost::hash, or should I look into something else ? Also, why do you recommend a set, isn't a map faster ?
Thank you for your answer !

Comment: Yes, hash_combine looks appropriate for this.

Comment: Collision with a 64b key and hash is "pretty unlikely". You need roughly N^(1/2) to see any meaningful chance of collision in a key space of size N. That means you need about 4 billion entries in your hash map before chance of collision becomes "signifcant". If your hash is going to have less than 1M entries then you might consider collision an impossibility... (hardware failure is more likely, your death in a car accident is more likely, etc .. you have bigger concerns than collisions.) This may mean you can use simpler algorithms. (Though you better be using a known good hash algorithm...)

Comment: The equality operator needs to test the objects for _equality_.  It is OK for it to be slow, but it must be 100% correct.  So just code it in the obvious way.  The hash function should endeavor to produce a different hash for different objects, but it need not to do 100% of the time, and it needs to be _fast_.  Re-read @Kerrick's answer until you understand it, because everything he says is correct

Answer (score 2):

forget about hash; there is nothing (at least from your question) that suggests you have a meaningful key;

lets take a step back and rephrase your actual performance goals:

- you want to quickly validate no duplicates ever exist for any of your State objects

comment if i need to add others.

From the aforementioned goal, and from your comment i would suggest you use actually a [ordered_set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/) rather than an unordered_map. Yes, the ordered search uses binary search O(log (n)) while unordered uses lookup O(1).

However, the difference is that with this approach you need the ordered_set **ONLY** to check that a similar state doesn't exist already *when you are about to create a new one*, that is, at State **creation-time**.

In **all** the other lookups, you actually don't need to look into the ordered_set! because you already have the key; State*, and the key can access the value by the magic dereference operator: *key

so with this approach, you only are using the ordered_set as an **[index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_%28database%29)** to verify States on creation time only. In all the other cases, you access your State with the dereference operator of your pointer-value key.

if all the above wasn't enough to convince you, here is the final nail in the coffin of the idea of using a hash to quickly determine equality; hash function has a small probability of collision, but as the number of states will grow, that probability will become complete certainty. So depending on your fault-tolerance, you are going to deal with state collisions (and from your question and the number of States you are expecting to deal, it seems you will deal with a lot of them)

For this to work, you obviously need the compare predicate to test for all the internal properties of your state (giroscope, thrusters, accelerometers, proton rays, etc.)

Comment: So do you recommend I avoid hash functions and values alltogether ? Uniqueness is essential, fast lookup is just something I am wishing for. However In an ordered state, according to what key do they get ordered ? Pointer value ?